# How to enable and disable Start Recording button in console preference link(WLST Script Recording tab) in Weblogic using wlst and python

Tags: python, scripting, preferences, recording, wlst

In Weblogic Console if I go to "preferences" link there we will get "WLST Script Recording" option. There manually I can start recording and stop recording but I want to do that same thing using wlst/python script. Can anyone help me how to do that using python script?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fASM3.png)

I want to automate this console recording option via backend wlst/python script. So if there is any way to do that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.